# Signalr with sql server- 401 Un-Authorization Error while page loading(page is loading in 7-8 minutes)

Tags: signalr, signal-processing

implemented Signalr with sql server long back for a page. if the page load is taking >7 minutes we are receiving response as 'pong' and 401 Un-Authorization Error in IE 10. same functionality is working fine for 2 minutes page load.